# UiTableView crashes on section header tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

ExpandableTableView crashes on second click. Following method will be invoked in clicking section header.

```
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    NSString *selectedCountryName = [self.countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int selectedCountryId = [DataAdapter getCountryId:[self managedObjectContext] forCountryName:selectedCountryName] ;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
        for (int i=0; i<[self.countries count]; i++) {
            if (indexPath.section==i) {
                [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
                [self fetchEntities:(int)indexPath.section withCountryId : selectedCountryId];
            }
        }

        [self animateView:gestureRecognizer];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    });
}
```

> The issue is that Im getting the following error while clicking the
>   second section.
>
> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

What am I missing?

Comment: error clearly says that there is no data in array of rows in `section 0`!

Comment: Its expandable tableview. so when the user clicks the second `section 1`,the number of rows in `section0 ` will be 0

Comment: then how you can get indexpath like this `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];` if there is no rows ?? with this indexpath if you reload section then it will crash because there is no row with index `0`!

Comment: Im using the code in `http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html` and modified it to suit my case ;(

Comment: are you seen this `invalid number of rows`

Comment: Ya bro ;( .... unable to debug it

Comment: any ideas?......